# Kestrel self-hosted web API connection timing out

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, windows-services, kestrel-http-server, kestrel

I have a self hosted web API using .Net 6. It is deployed as a window service. I can access locally from browser, using the domain name and port, but can't do that from another machine. I have define inbound rules for the ports in the firewall setting. This is Program.cs

```
var webApplicationOptions = new WebApplicationOptions() { ContentRootPath = AppContext.BaseDirectory, Args = args, ApplicationName = System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().ProcessName };
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(webApplicationOptions);
builder.Host.UseWindowsService();  

builder.Services.AddControllers();

// Learn more about configuring Swagger/OpenAPI at https://aka.ms/aspnetcore/swashbuckle
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();

builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
{
    c.IncludeXmlComments(Path.Combine(AppContext.BaseDirectory,
        $"{Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Name}.xml"));

    c.AddSecurityDefinition("Bearer", new OpenApiSecurityScheme
    {
        In = ParameterLocation.Header,
        Description = "Please enter a valid token",
        Name = "Authorization",
        Type = SecuritySchemeType.Http,
        BearerFormat = "JWT",
        Scheme = "Bearer"
    });
    c.AddSecurityRequirement(new OpenApiSecurityRequirement
    {
        {
            new OpenApiSecurityScheme
            {
                Reference = new OpenApiReference
                {
                    Type=ReferenceType.SecurityScheme,
                    Id="Bearer"
                }
            },
            new string[]{}
        }
    });
});


// generate lowercase URLs
builder.Services.Configure<RouteOptions>(options =>
{
    options.LowercaseUrls = true;
});

var configurationBuilder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
    .SetBasePath(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory)
    .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")
    .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{builder.Environment.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true);
var configuration = configurationBuilder.Build();


var loggerConfig = new LoggerConfiguration()
    .ReadFrom.Configuration(configuration);
var logger = loggerConfig.CreateLogger();
var key = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(configuration["Jwt:Secret"]!);

builder.Services.AddLogging(loggingBuilder =>
{
    loggingBuilder.ClearProviders();
    loggingBuilder.AddSerilog(logger);
});

builder.Services.AddAuthentication(options =>
    {
        options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        options.DefaultScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    })

// Adding Jwt Bearer
    .AddJwtBearer(options =>
    {
        options.SaveToken = true;
        options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
        options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters()
        {
            ValidateIssuer = true,
            ValidateAudience = true,
            ValidAudience = configuration["JWT:ValidAudience"],
            ValidIssuer = configuration["JWT:ValidIssuer"],
            IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(key)
        };
        options.Events = new JwtBearerEvents
        {
            OnChallenge = async context =>
            {
                // Call this to skip the default logic and avoid using the default response
                context.HandleResponse();
                context.Response.StatusCode = StatusCodes.Status401Unauthorized;
                context.Response.ContentType = "application/json";

                var result = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new
                {
                    code = ResponseCode.UnauthorizedDueToInvalidToken.ToCode(),
                    message = ResponseCode.UnauthorizedDueToInvalidToken.ToMessage(),
                });

                context.Response.WriteAsync(result);
            }
        };
    });

var tokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
{
    ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
    IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(key),
    ValidateIssuer = false,
    ValidateAudience = false,
    ValidateLifetime = false,
    RequireExpirationTime = false,

    // Allow to use seconds for expiration of token
    // Required only when token lifetime less than 5 minutes
    // THIS ONE
    ClockSkew = TimeSpan.Zero
};

builder.Services.AddSingleton(tokenValidationParameters);

var app = builder.Build();
// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}


app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization(); 
app.MapControllers();
 
app.Run();
```

This is my Kestrel section in appsetting.json

```
"Kestrel": {
    "Endpoints": {
      "Http": {
        "Url": "http://0.0.0.0:7504"
      },
      "Https": {
        "Url": "https://*:7503",
        "Certificate": {
          "Path": "D:/Certificates/Cert.pfx",
          "Password": "********"
        }
      }
    }
```

Comment: Check Antivirus .... I had similar problems with ports...

Comment: Can you please show an example of locally accessible address?

Comment: @GuruStron https://example.com:7503.api/v1/myController
When I try https://localhost:7503/api/v1/myController it says "This server could not prove that it is localhost; its security certificate is from example.com"

Comment: I even tried "Url": "https://example.com:7503",

Comment: have you tried builder.WebHost.UseUrls("http://*:port"); ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It wasn't any config or code issue. It was network security issue on the host network.